# Parse Thor options outside of class

Tags: ruby

I would like to parse again some Thor options **outside** of a Thor class as I have no control on the Thor class and the instance of it. Unfortunately the `parse` function is not for getting the values out of the argv. What I already looked for:

1. https://www.rubydoc.info/github/wycats/thor/Thor/Option#parse-class_method
2. https://github.com/rails/thor/blob/main/lib/thor/parser/options.rb
3. https://github.com/rails/thor/blob/main/lib/thor/parser/option.rb

I whould like the following:

```
Class Mycli < Thor
  def someOptions
    option :aaaa, aliases: :a, type: :string,
    desc: "AAAAAAAAAAAAAA"
  option :bbbb, aliases: :b, type: :string,
    desc: "BBBBBBBBBBBBBB"
  end
...
end

# code having control on:
options = Mycli.someOptions
r = options.parse_arg($ARGV)  # ["-a" "stringA", "-b", "stringB"]
p r[:a]  # "StringA"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am misunderstanding the question but I am unsure why you need `thor` for this.

Instead you can achieve the desired outcome by simply using an [`OptionParser`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.1.0/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html).

A simplistic example would look like

```
require 'optparse'
options = {}
OptionParser.new do |opts|
  opts.on('-aNAME', '--aaaa=AVALUE')
  opts.on('-b', '--bbbb=BVALUE')
end.parse!(into: options)

p options[:aaaa]
```

but you can certainly expand the usage:

```
require 'optparse'
class MyCli
  attr_reader :options

  def initialize
    @options = {}
  end

  def [](elem)
    options[elem]
  end

  def parse(options)
    _parser.parse!(options)
  end

  private

  def _parser
    OptionParser.new do |opts|
      opts.on('-aNAME', '--aaaa=AVALUE') do |v|
        options[:a] = v
      end

      opts.on('-b', '--bbbb=BVALUE') do |v|
        options[:b] = v
      end
    end
  end
end

r = MyCli.new
r.parse(ARGV)
p r[:a]
```

Then call as `ruby mycli.rb -a stringA -b stringB` and it will output `"stringA"` to STDOUT.

[Example](https://replit.com/@engineersmnky/SimpleOptionsParser#main.rb)

Comment: I have a program allowing to add plugins but not giving access to variables passed though cli. I wanted to reuse the thor cli to access those args and have an as possible clean integration. I will see if they is a response with and already defined and lunched thor CLI, else I will use optparse to reparse the cli and validate your answer.